# Centering a scaled SCNNode on top of another SCNNode

Tags: swift, arkit

in my new ARKit app the user can place objects on the detected plane. The plane is detected just fine and when the user touches the plane, a new node (a SCNBox) is created and dropped on the plane. This step works just fine.

However, I would like that the newly generated box (a more complex model later) is dropped at the exact center of the model.

Here is my code:

```
fileprivate func pasteModel(hitResult: ARHitTestResult)
{
    guard let model = self.model else { return }

    // Get the tapped plane.
    if let anchor = hitResult.anchor
    {
        if let plane = self.planes[anchor.identifier]
        {
            // Get the dimensions of the model.
            let widthModel = CGFloat(0.20)
            let lengthModel = CGFloat(0.20)

            let box = SCNBox(width: widthModel, height: widthModel, length: widthModel, chamferRadius: 0.0)
            box.firstMaterial = SCNMaterial()
            box.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan

            let node = SCNNode(geometry: box)
            plane.addChildNode(node)

            // Get the dimensions of the tapped plane.
            let width = plane.width
            let length = plane.length

            // Calculate the scale (i.e. how much bigger the model is). Keep the ratio, so use the bigger side.
            let scaleWidth = widthModel / width
            let scaleHeight = lengthModel / length

            let scale: Float = Float(1.0 / max(scaleWidth, scaleHeight))

            node.scale = SCNVector3Make(scale, scale, scale)
            node.position = plane.position

            // Check how much the model is away from the center point.
            let centerPlane = self.getCenter(ofNode: plane)
            let centerNode = self.getCenter(ofNode: node)

            let distanceX = centerPlane.x - centerPlane.z
            let distanceZ = centerNode.x - centerNode.z

            let translation = SCNVector3Make(distanceX, self.MODEL_OFFSET, distanceZ)
            node.localTranslate(by: translation)

            // After the model has been scaled and positoned properly, the physics body is added.
            node.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.dynamic, shape: nil)
            node.physicsBody?.mass = self.MODEL_MASS
            node.physicsBody?.angularVelocityFactor = SCNVector3Zero // Prevent model rotation.
        }
    }
}

fileprivate func getCenter(ofNode node: SCNNode) -> SCNVector3
{
    let widthNode = node.boundingBox.max.x - node.boundingBox.min.x
    let lengthNode = node.boundingBox.max.z - node.boundingBox.min.z
    let centerNode = SCNVector3Make(node.position.x + Float(widthNode / 2), node.position.y, node.position.z + Float(lengthNode / 2))

    return centerNode
}
```

Here is a short overview of my approach:

- Get the plane detected by ARKit.
- Create a cube and scale it to the dimensions of the plane - the bigger side is used for scaling.
- Get the center point of both the plane and the cube.
- Translate the cube so the center points align.

Unfortunately the model is not centered. Where is my error?

Comment: You may try to play around with the pivot point of the object.